# OrientDB- Cannot save Javascript function in distributed mode

Tags: orientdb

I have been creating and using server side javascript functions with no problem on standalone mode. When I switch to distributed mode (launching dserver.sh instead of server.sh) I can not save updates or create new functions in the studio. The save button doesn't work.

The database itself is working fine in distributed mode.

Comment: Which OrientDB version?

Comment: OrientDB 2.2.0 community

Comment: could you retry using 2.2.14?

Comment: I tried with the new version and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updating to latest version fixed the issue.